# laravel monitor check is getting failed

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, server-monitoring

I am using spatie/laravel-server-monitor package . This package is Failed when run `php artisan server-monitor:run-checks`

Here is the error

```
update
  `checks`
set
  `last_run_output` = '{\"output\":\"\",\"error_output\":\"ssh: connect to host xdock.com.au port 22: Connection timed out\r\n\",\"exit_code\":255,\"exit_code_text\":\"Unknown error\"}',
  `checks`.`updated_at` = '2020-09-29 19:28:16'
where
  `id` = 5
```

host name is correct . but still  giving this error

Comment: This is not a code issue, but connection details issue. Port 22 means SSH, does the client/server that you execute this code from have the appropiate ssh keys? Can you access the host through your own terminal?

Comment: yes i am running command on server at the moment

Comment: helo are you there?

Comment: DO i need to add ssh key on server?